# Minimum amount of primes between squared primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> $\forall $ $p_{n}$, $p_{n+1} \in \mathbb{P}$, $\:$ $p^2_{n+1} = p^2_{n} +\omega_{n} p_{n} + \phi_{n} : \phi_{n} , \omega_{n} \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ \phi_{n} < p_{n}$, $\:$ $\Rightarrow$  $\:$$\exists$ atleast $ \omega_{n}$ prime numbers in the interval $(p^2_{n},p^2_{n+1})$

How would you prove this?

Comment: I would be pessimistic about a "simple" proof, also a not so simple proof.

Comment: there is no chance of proving that there are any primes at all in your interval. There is a huge gap between what can be proved and what is believed (and supported by computations) in the subject of prime gaps. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Comment: It seems intuitive that you would be able to prove something like this, by noting that all odd numbers $\in [2,9)$ are prime numbers , all odd numbers not divisible by 3 $\in [9,25)$ are prime numbers etc.

Comment: @Brad, While I support Will's overall view expressed above, you _can_ get a number of primes in your interval simply by repeatedly applying the Prime Number Theorem.  Not nearly as many as you want though.

Comment: @Doc, Would $\frac{p^2_{n+1}}{\ln(p^2_{n+1})} - \frac{p^2_{n}}{\ln(p^2_{n})}$ be an approximation of the amount of prime numbers in this interval, or is it a lower bound of the amount of primes?

Comment: @Brad, I'm not an expert in this area, but I would say neither.  What you're using is an asymptotic result (namely that $\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\ln{x}}$, where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes up to $x$).  It is well known that the error in this approximation goes to zero as $x\to \infty$, but it is still an approximation.  To obtain something more precise, you would have to go into some quite elaborate bounds (Rosser's theorem comes to mind).  It won't be easy, but perhaps very worthwhile.

Comment: @Brad, me again.  You asked if it would be an approximation, and I basically said "No, it would be an approximation." Pretty cryptic on my part, no?  What I really meant to suggest is that the approximation would only become reliable for very large $n$, whereas your conjecture is stated for all $n$.  My response was really referring moreso to the conjecture than to your later question.