# There exist infinitely many prime numbers $p≥2$ and there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $k^2+1=p+m$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I am asking about the validity of the following conjecture:

**Conjecture**: There exist infinitely many prime numbers $p≥2$ and there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $k^2+1=p+m$ with $1≤m≤p-1$.

However, I am not able to prove or disprove it.

Comment: For $p=2$, you’d require $m=1$, and $2+1-1$ is not the square of an integer

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: You are asking to find $k,m$ such that $k^2 = p + (m-1)$ with $0 \leq m \leq p-2$. By varying $m$, we are looking for a square among the numbers $p,\ldots, 2p-2$. This has nothing to do with prime numbers anymore - it is easy to show that this is possible for any ''integer'' $p \geq 6$.

Comment: @MikeDaas: Can you give a proof for this. Here $m>0$.

Comment: I will give you a hint. The ratio of two consecutive squares will tend to 1, so finding a square between $n$ and $2n-2$ should be very common for larger numbers. For intuition: for $n = 100$, we are looking for squares between $100$ and $198$. There are many, e.g. 121, 144, 169, 196. It is not a rare occurence.

Comment: @MikeDaas: In fact I am not an expert on number theory.

Comment: This is not about number theory. A more concrete hint, if $k^2 \leq n < (k+1)^2$, try to show that for large enough $n$, we will have $n < (k+1)^2 < 2n - 2$. There's the square you are looking for

Comment: @MikeDaas: The problem when $p$ is a prime is very difficult. See https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.facm/1323705816#:~:text=A%20well%2Dknown%20conjecture%20about,assumption%20of%20the%20Riemann%20Hypothesis.

Comment: That is a different problem from what you wrote in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's note (usual notation) by $\pi(n)$ - [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and $p_n$-$n$'th prime number. We [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422179/does-this-conjecture-about-prime-numbers-exist-if-n-is-a-prime-then-there-is/1427154#1427154)
$$p_{\pi (k)} \leq k < p_{\pi (k)+1}$$
or
$$p_{\pi (k^2)} < k^2 < p_{\pi (k^2)+1}$$
We can add $m-1\geq2$ such that
$$p_{\pi (k^2)} <p_{\pi (k^2)} +m-1 =k^2 < p_{\pi (k^2)+1}$$
It has to be $m-1\geq2$, because $m-1=1$ would lead to $p_{\pi (k^2)}=k^2-1=(k-1)(k+1)$ (not a prime for large $k$'s).
Finally, from the strict version of the [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)
$$2\leq m-1 < p_{\pi (k^2)+1}-p_{\pi (k^2)}\leq p_{\pi (k^2)}-2$$

---

**Summary:** we have found a subsequence of prime numbers $\left(p_{\pi (k^2)}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, $k>1$ satisfying:
$$k^2 +1=p_{\pi (k^2)} +m$$
with $3\leq m\leq p_{\pi (k^2)}-1$. It yields infinite **different** primes because:

- [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) or
- from [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) $$\pi((2\cdot k)^2)=\pi(4\cdot k^2)>\pi(2\cdot k^2)>\pi(k^2) \Rightarrow p_{\pi((2\cdot k)^2)} > p_{\pi(k^2)}$$

whichever version you prefer.

Comment: But $m>0$, then the interval ends in $2p-1$ not $2p-2$. So you need to add $m$ only.

Comment: @Safwane I think you can deal with the borderline cases. Take the strict version of he Bertrand's postulate $p_{k+1}<2p_k -2$. Take odd $n$'s  such that $n^2-p_{\pi(n^2)}\geq 2$. You will get infinity anyway.

Comment: @Safwane it is a prime. Take $k \to k^2$, then find $\pi(k^2)$, then find the prime indexed by $\pi(k^2)$, which is $p_{\pi(k^2)}$, according to the notations.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that since I am not well familiar with number theory.

Comment: Any reference for the proof of: $$p_{\pi (k)} \leq k < p_{\pi (k)+1}$$. By the way an unconditional proof is better, so there is no need to use the Legendre's conjecture.

Comment: @Safwane that's an easy result from the definition on $\pi(n)$ - the number of primes $\leq n$, which are $p_1,p_2,...,p_{\pi(n)}$. Thus $p_{\pi(n)} \leq n$. Obviously $n < p_{\pi(n)+1}$, otherwise $\pi(n)+1 = \pi(n)$.

Comment: Thank you. You write in your profile that you are a Software Engineer. But your answers are fine and deep like any expert in number theory.

Comment: @Safwane thank you. Well, not everything is for the profile ;) ... I did a PhD in Applied Mathematics and also specialise in cryptography, which requires a fair amount of number theory.

Answer (score 3):

Following from the comment by Mike Daas that you are asking whether a number $k^2$ falls among $p,\dots 2p-2$: For any suitably large square number $k^2$, we can always pick the largest prime number $p_k<k^2$.

Assume that $k^2>2p_k-2$. Bertrand's postulate assures us that for suitably large $p$, there is at least one prime number in any interval $(p,2p-2)$. So if $k^2$ is not in the interval $(p_k,2p_k-2)$, then there is another  prime number in that interval that is smaller than $k^2$, and $p_k$ is not the largest prime smaller than $k^2$. In other words, *every* suitably large $k^2$ falls in an interval $(p,2p-2)$.

Comment: But $m>0$, then the interval ends in $2p-1$ not $2p-2$.

Comment: Change "$-2$" to "$-1$" in my answer and the same logic applies.