# There exist infinitely many prime numbers $p≥2$ and there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $f(k)=p+m$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

The following result:

**Lemma**: There exist infinitely many prime numbers $p≥2$ and there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $k^2+1=p+m$ with $1≤m≤p-1$.

is true as shown in [There exist infinitely many prime numbers $p≥2$ and there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $k^2+1=p+m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899131/there-exist-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-p%e2%89%a52-and-there-exist-positive-integer).

Now, consider an **irreducible integer-valued polynomials** $f(x)$ with integer coefficients.

Then I am asking about the necessary condition or possible forms of polynomials $f(x)$ verifying the following result:

There exist infinitely many prime numbers $p≥2$ and there exist positive integers $k,m$ such that $f(k)=p+m$ with $1≤m≤p-1$.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is [this application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem#Extensions_and_generalizations) of Green–Tao theorem. It's just a brainstorming ...

Comment: @rtybase: Yes. this is a good idea.

Comment: It has nothing to do with primes, only the growth of polynomials matters. If the leading coefficient of $f$ is positive, then $f(k) > 0$ and [if $f$ is not constant, which I assume henceforth] $f(k+1) > f(k)$ for all sufficiently large $k$. And $$\lim_{k \to +\infty} \frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} = 1\,,$$ so for all large enough $k$ we have $f(k) < f(k+1) < \sqrt[3]{2}\cdot f(k)$. That means if $n$ is a sufficiently large positive integer, then there are at least three consecutive values of $f$ between $n$ and $2n$ (inclusive), i.e. $$n \leqslant f(k-1) < f(k) < f(k+1) \leqslant 2n$$ for suitable $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Did you mean that we can replace primes $p$ by any integer $n$  in the above equation.

Comment: Yes, for all sufficiently large integers $n$ (in particular for all sufficiently large primes) there are $k,m$ with $1 \leqslant m \leqslant n-1$ such that $f(k) = n + m$, provided that $f$ is not constant and has positive leading coefficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you, this is a great idea.